# Get specific Tables with Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am having trouble getting some specific table's with HTML Agility Pack. I cannot change the actual HTML either, so I can't use other ID"s or Classes or anything.

Can someone show me how I would access each individual table of the following?

```
<table class="newTable">
      //table 1 contents
    <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
         //table 1 - A contents
    </table>
</table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="newTable">
     //table 2 contents
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
        //table 2 - A contents
    </table>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
       //table 2 - B contents
    </table>
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
       //table 2 - C contents
    </table>
</table>
<table>
     //table 3 contents
</table>
```

Right now if I were to call the following

```
HtmlNode table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table");
foreach (var cell in table.SelectNodes("//tr/td"))
{
     string someVariable = cell.InnerText
}
```

I would go through everything. I want to be able to access tables differently to correlate where I am storing the data.

I have tried looking at something like

`doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[1]");`

but using an index does not seem to work, when I try to specify a table with it, it still reads in all tables or none.

Same thing applies to this, it either does not work at all or gets everything.

```
foreach (var cell in table.SelectNodes("//table").Skip(some_number))
{
     string someVariable = cell.InnerText
}
```

I am using the NuGet package of HTML Agility Pack 1.4.9

**EDIT:**

My attempt to get ONLY Table 1 - A's contents. Both give null or endcodingfound exceptions.

`HtmlNode table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table/tr/td/table[1]");`

`HtmlNode table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[1]/tr/td/table[1]");`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is with your second call, the "//tr/td" will go back to the root element. Your indexer is the correct solution for the first part of your problem, the second can be fixed by specifying that you want to navigate from where you are at:

```
HtmlNode table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[1]");
foreach (var cell in table.SelectNodes(".//tr/td")) // **notice the .**
{
     string someVariable = cell.InnerText
}
```

Not sure what else is going on, but by [extending your test table to this code](http://pastebin.com/RUnd6htK), the following just works on my test. It might mean that you need to share a little more context.

This is the Document I used for the tests:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="newTable">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
                    <tr><td>
                        //table 1 - A contents
                    </td></tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="newTable">
        <tr>
            <td>
                //table 2 contents
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            //table 2 - A contents
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            //table 2 - B contents
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table width="100%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            //table 2 - C contents
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                //table 3 contents
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

And this the code to extract the values you're after:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(text);

var node1A = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[1]//table[1]");
string content1A = node1A.InnerText;
Console.WriteLine(content1A);

var node2C = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[2]//table[3]");
string content2C = node2C.InnerText;
Console.WriteLine(content2C);
```

Shows:

[image]

### Update

Ok, I took your actual HTML and I get a NullReference as well. There must be something that greatly confuses the Agility Pack, not sure why. Some experimentation with the Linq API seems to work though, I hope it can be an alternative for you:

```
var table = doc.DocumentNode.DescendantsAndSelf("table").Skip(1).First().Descendants("table").First();
var tds   = table.Descendants("td");
```

Comment: So, when I say the above example it works. However, if I say `table[2]` for example, Agility get's a `NullReference`... I am not sure why this is. I also am not sure what `table[2]` points to. In my above example would `table[2]` point to `//table 2 contents` or is it trying to find a second sub-table within `//table 1 contents`. Can you show me an additional example(s) of how to access sub-tables, versus main tables like in my example above. I am getting confused on how the navigation works for index specificity.

Comment: I added two examples of how I am trying to get the contents for Table 1 - A. I can attempt to build a mock copy of what I am pulling later on as the current data contains business information. But what I posted above is the exact layout of the tables. Except each table itself has a variety of td's and tr's. I just need help with getting data ONLY from specific tables I choose. i.e. Only Table 1 - A, or only Table 2 - C.

Comment: Awesome! This works great! One quick question, what if I wanted to get just Table 1's contents, but NOT any sub-tables, like Table 1 - A? I tried this `".//tr[not(.//td[@colspan='3'])]/td[not(.//table)]"` which skips td's with a `colspan=3`, but it still enters the table of Table 1 - A

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! Unfortunately the `.SelectSingleNode("//table[2]");` always stills errors with a `nullreference exception`, I use the exact structure above in my example so idk why it can't find indexes..., //table[1] does not work either, I just select a single table instead. :(

Comment: There are some `<p>`'s involved. Here is what Table 2 looks like. I am trying to get table 2 - a right now: http://www.pastebucket.com/57251

Comment: and I am trying this to get the text. `HtmlNode table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[2]//table[1]");` And then.. `foreach (var cell in table.SelectNodes(".//td/p"))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62282/discussion-between-austin-and-jessehouwing).